# Disable some URLs on robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt

I have a site with URLs of the style:

```
https://www.example.com/16546/slug-title
```

What is the rule to add in robots.txt to disable these URLs?

I want to keep the public URLs `https://www.example.com/terms`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wildcards in your `robots.txt`, but that will not work for your url format `/<id>/<slug>`.

If you use the format `/article/<id>/<slug>` it could work with (not tested):

```
Disallow: /article
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with blocking all URLs whose path starts with `0`-`9`, you can use:

```
Disallow: /0
Disallow: /1
Disallow: /2
Disallow: /3
Disallow: /4
Disallow: /5
Disallow: /6
Disallow: /7
Disallow: /8
Disallow: /9
```

This will block URLs like

```
https://www.example.com/1
```

```
https://www.example.com/16
```

```
https://www.example.com/165/foo
```